# iphone dev how to check notification's launch button pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have Implemented Ray wenderlich's these

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

awesome tutorials on APNS. Every thing is working fine, now what i want is that in case application is not running and notification arrives and displays on device now if user presses the launch button i want to display a particular screen other  than home screen (i have tab bar application with splash screen displays first for 5 seconds then home screen displays which is on zero index), means i want to display a screen which is on third index, plz. guide me in this, is there a way to do this? and how thanx and regards... Saad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have different flows for when the app is active & for when the app is not active (reg. notifications) you can do it like so -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
    {
        // app active.
    }
    else 
    {
        // app not active
        self.tabController.selectedIndex = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx Srikar means if i want to display a view which is 4th tab or 3rd index then i will code in else portion? am i right?

Comment: i did this to check if i got the message in case if app is not running but no alert displays

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
 //count = 0;
 NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
 NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
 UIAlertView * view=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:alertValue delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [view show];
 [view release];
 [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:YES];
 
 }

Comment: I also checked that the application state is active or not but displaying the alert.

Comment: i did this (in next comment) in application didReceiveRemoteNotification, but the alert is not displaying when i press launch button.

Comment: if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
    {
}
else 
    {
  NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
  UIAlertView * view=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"app from quit mode" message:alertValue delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [view show];
  [view release];
  }

Comment: is the notification coming at all? if yes then this should work! cant think of a reason why it shouldn't. This code that i have put here has been running for atleast 1 year now & is in appstore too...